# Dynamics AX 2009: Calculating fixed assets depreciation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I’m facing an issue in SSRS Fixed assets depreciation reports which is how to calculate the depreciation value?
I’m calculation with this formula ( (ACQUISITIONPRICE / Depreciation Period) * Depreciation Remain) but the value is incorrect let’s take an example,

ASSETID,ASSETGROUP,NAME,LIFETIME,LIFETIMEREST,ACQUISITIONPRICE

BLDRNV53,Building R,WATER PROOFING WORK,60,-57,370

The Calculation In SQL Query:

```
SELECT     ASSETTABLE.ASSETID, ASSETTABLE.ASSETGROUP, ASSETTABLE.NAME, (ASSETBOOK.LIFETIMEREST * (ASSETBOOK.ACQUISITIONPRICE / ASSETBOOK.LIFETIME)) as AccDep
FROM         ASSETBOOK INNER JOIN
                      ASSETTABLE ON ASSETBOOK.ASSETID = ASSETTABLE.ASSETID AND ASSETBOOK.DATAAREAID = ASSETTABLE.DATAAREAID
WHERE       (ASSETBOOK.DEPRECIATION = 1) AND ASSETBOOK.STATUS = 1
```

---

Example:
( (370/60) * -57) =  -351.5 But System report is calculating it -350.550 there is 0.95 difference and the whole depreciation values have small difference like this.

Please Help

Comment: Is the calculation done in the database query or using an expression in the report? Please provide code for the query or expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the equation missing is the Fixed Assets Scrape Value which is 1.000 for the Asset in the example, so the  equation is `(((Acquisition Price - Scrape Value) / Depreciation Period) * Depreciation Remain)`

let's fill it with numbers: 
**(((370 - 1) / 60) * -57) = -350.550**

Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand where the `-350.550` value is coming from. I wasn't able to reproduce it in my tests.

My recommendation is to ensure the column datatype for `ACQUISITIONPRICE` accurately represents the type of data stored in the database. Given the name, I assume the value stored represents some type of currency. The [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) datatype is probably a good choice, something like DECIMAL(10,2). Increase the precision as needed to satisfy your requirements.

Perform all calculations needed **before** rounding values, only round if needed in the presentation layer.

Sample T-SQL follows to demonstrate effects of different datatypes on your result :

```
-- create temporary table, columns with integer datatype
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Asset') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Asset;
CREATE TABLE #Asset (
    LifetimeRest INTEGER NOT NULL,
    AcquisitionPrice INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Lifetime INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- load sample data
INSERT INTO #Asset VALUES (-57, 370, 60);

-- result is -342 with integer datatype and no conversion
SELECT
    IntegerCalculation = LifetimeRest * (AcquisitionPrice / Lifetime)
FROM #Asset;

-- result is -351.500000 is with dynamic decimal conversion
SELECT
    DynamicDecimalCalculation = LifetimeRest *
                                (CAST(AcquisitionPrice AS DECIMAL) / Lifetime)
FROM #Asset;

-- change price datatype to decimal with consistent precision and scale
ALTER TABLE #Asset ALTER COLUMN AcquisitionPrice DECIMAL(10, 2);

-- result is -351.4999620 with static decimal precision and scale, 
-- and no on the fly conversion
SELECT
    StaticDecimalCalculation = LifetimeRest * (AcquisitionPrice / Lifetime)
FROM #Asset;

-- cleanup
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Asset') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Asset;
```

Comment: -350.550 comes in Fixed Assets Balance Morphex Report in AX 2009, it's calculating using a Class called `AssetSumCalc` which I can't reverse enginner what it's doing. But based on your answer the difference is not equal -350.500, you answer is help me about rounding but not about this much difference "0.95", Thanks for you're help :)